# UITableView Reloads on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have some weird behavior differences running my app on an iPhone and iPad I am trying to understand.

I have the following method to reload a `UITableView` when a user starts to edit a text field.  It works 100% correctly on my iPhone, however when I load the app onto my iPad, the table does not `reloadData` when this function is called.  I can see that the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` function is called (and all code inside it) however the table does not `reloadData:` when the app is run on my iPad.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    self.concatLabel.hidden = false;

    NSLog(@"BEGIN EDITING");

    self.messageField.text = nil;
    self.concatLabel.text = nil;
    [self.arySelectionState removeAllObjects];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

My iPhone is running iOS 8.1, while my iPad is running iOS 7.0

My deployment target is set to 7.0.  I switched the Deployment target device from iPhone to Universal and I have the same issue.

I would appreciate any insight or advice.

Comment: Are you sure that your self.tableView is not `nil`?

Comment: My guess is that you linked well the tableView in iPhone but you didn't link it to the controller on iPad